# Sporadic SQL Timeouts with joins, good index

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, timeout

I have a query that timeouts in some instances but not others. I am using sql server 2008, mvc3, ef.

The query is rather large (EF code), however, after investigating in QA Using the exact query that's in Profiler), all branches use index seek. It's a two or three table join, depending on exactly which query (about 4 different ones, with 4 variations each based on exactly what column I'm querying on). The tables have about 400k, 100k, 1.2m rows. However, I get timeouts even on the 400k - 100k join. I am paging 50 records at a time, but I'm getting timeouts on the count as, well.

I am looking for some advice on how to determine what's causing the timeout. Since it runs and displays on the page within 5 seconds in some instances and timeouts on others, I don't think it's the query. I rather not increase the timeout threshold.

I have tried using the reports in SSMS looking for blocking transactions, resource locking, I have set read not commited, looked at profile tables...

The one thing that is suspect is that these tables are updated daily, once - utilizing a larg delete and bulk import. Could statitics be off or the index? I rebuild most of these index nightly, but not sure on these tables. Is there a way to verify this is the case? I could rebuild the index after import time, wouldn't be too much downtime and it's better than sporadic timeouts. But I'm still not sure if it's this.

Comment: Any chance of blocking?  It sounds to me like contention.  If someone else is updating or selecting with an unexpected level of lock escalation (i.e. SELECT ... WITH (TABLOCKX)) it could cause this.

Comment: No blocking transaction or any major locks - I've been watching that like an eagle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise doing a reorganize on your index (so that it still stays online for your users) straight after you import to see if that helps. I would check the fragmentation of your indexes after an import to see what state they are in and if it would help or not.

Another thing I can think of, off the top of my head is that your queries may be affected by DOP (Degrees of Parrallesism < can never spell that word sorry :( ), so have a look at each query that is timing out, by taking a look at it's query plan. If you hover over the lines for the join's etc you will see the estimated number of rows vs the actual number of rows. If, for example, you are expecting 500k rows but returning 10 rows, then SQLServer is over complicating your queries execution plan.

We can alter the way that the query runs using [Query Hints (MSDN LINK)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181714.aspx)

HTH,

Stu

Comment: I think this might be the real issue. I'll take a look at the parrallism and see what displays - I've never head that tip, thanks.